# Windows 10 COMException when loading geckofx 45.0.34

Tags: c#, xpcom, geckofx

I am running **same installed copy of two windows 10** running into vmware. Into one of them I installed Visual Studio 2013 and created a program using Geckofx 45.0.34. Its running there perfectly. But when I tried to run generated exe with gecko dlls and Firefox folder, into 2nd win10 (which does not have VS installed), I am getting this error:[image]

But I made sure that xulpath is accurate. Infact I am trying to fix it for last few hours. Also I tried to install .net 4.5.2 which is required for this geckofx. But its saying, upper version already installed. Am I missing something ? Here I am getting the error:

```
Xpcom.EnableProfileMonitoring = false;
Xpcom.Initialize(xulPath);
```

Comment: does your solution reference mozglue? if so, can you read its path? what is it?

Comment: Yes, of course. it has this mozglue dll file into the specified path

Comment: which is where the dll is in the second machine, right?

Comment: Main confusing thing is, 2 OS are same, I installed one of them first, then copy the 2nd one from it.

Comment: but the dll is there in the second machine?

Comment: Yes, the mozpath has all the required files, I made sure of it.

Comment: if you search it in your GAC (C:\Windows\assembly\gac_msil) in the first machine and in the second, do you find it both times? same path?

Comment: I have to check it. Let me check.

Comment: Yes, both have same path

Comment: Another thing is, I was having same error in machine 1 when I was trying to run it with target framework .net 4.5... then I installed 4.5.2 developer version and changed target framework and it fixed the problem

Comment: If I understand correctly, your dll is there and correctly referenced.
At this point, you are not missing that DLL but one of its dependecies.

A tool like [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) will help you find what you are missing.

Comment: Ok, let me check it But I copied all the files from nuget package.

Comment: You can dig out its dependencies by running dumpbin.exe /imports mozglue.dll.  You'll see it has a dependency on the VS2013 Visual C++ runtime libraries, msvcr120.dll and msvcp120.dll.  Not included in the nuget package, sloppy.  Download and run the VS2013 vcredist to fix.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the information. I will try it and let you know if it works.

Comment: Don't let me know, just post it and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I will do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) mentioned at comment the error was occurring not for having 
**msvcr120.dll** and **msvcp120.dll** which were not included into the nuget package. I just copied them from previous package folder (geckofx-45.0.22). And it worked.